# Setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.0, but is currently installed

Tags: .net, installation

I have a project with installer, which works on my computer and on one server. But on second server installation crashes. When I install it by cmd by msiexec /i msiPath /l*vx logPath I receive an error

```
Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.0.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(C): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000.  Please install Internet Information Server or a newer operating system and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.0.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.
Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed.
```

It's only part of log, if you need full tell me, and i'll paste it. .NET 4.0 is isntalled on server. Anyone can idea, have to resolve it?

Comment: It says that you are trying to run a .NET 4 app on a machine that boots Windows 2000.  That cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the full .NET Framework 4.0, not just the Client Profile.  Here is a link for the online installer:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17851

Comment: This installer give me only option to repair or remove. It means it's full .NET 40 fm installed, or I must choose repair?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785 has details on how to find the version of .net installed. You can follow the steps and check if you have the right 4.0 version installed

Comment: In registry i have these versions: http://imgur.com/piio2ga
So missing 4.0 framework isn't a reason